# How to Disable a UIView within a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, user-interaction

As the question states, is it possible to disable `userInteracion` within a `UICollectionViewCell`?

I know the code is to disable the view would be: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` in the .m file.

I have a button inside a Cell and I'm wondering if during the action of this button I could disable the entire View until the action is done (action: saving an image).

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Note: Cell has its own class. Inside the button with its action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description, the saving action is asynchronous, so you can insert `self.view.userInteractionEnable = NO` to the top selector of the button's touch event. and resume it after the saving.

```
- (void)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)button{
    //self.view.userInteractionEnable = NO;
    self.userInteractionEnable = NO;
    /* start saving the image  */

}
//here maybe the callback for your saving
- (void)savingImageFinished{
    //self.view.userInteractionEnable = YES;
    self.userInteractionEnable = YES;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I tried this but it throws an error: "Property 'view' not found on object of type..." since my cell has it's own class and the button is inside it, as well as the action method.

Comment: @adriennemhenry just as your title said, you want to disable the view in the cell, so whether the "view" is a property of your cell?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, that helped.. setting the property I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block with a completion handler for the button action. Disable the userInteraction within the block code and in the completion handler add `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES` to reenable it.

Comment: My cell has its own class so if I try implementing this in its .m file it throws an error:  " Property 'view' not found on object of type..."

Comment: If the view that contains the collection view is the owner of the cell class you can put the action for the cell buttons in the .m of the viewController

Comment: Yes, but in this case I need for it to be inside the cell class. Is there any way to do it from inside the cell class?

Comment: @adriennemhenry did tried `self.userInteractionEnable` to `YES` or `NO` instead of `self.view.userInteractionEnabled`?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Nah it didn't but figured it out. Setting the property of the view inside the cell class helped.